# Full height not stretching with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm hoping to get the blue area always fill up the remaining window height on the screen, however it doesn't appear at all.

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/usbs2/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="jumbo"></div>
Lalala
```

CSS:

```
*{margin: 0px; padding 0px;}

    #header {height: 30px; background: pink;}
    #jumbo {height: 100%; background: blue;}
```

So, why doesn't it work?

Comment: Although the answer works. I suggest that you are looking at this the wrong way, and that your body element or the parent of the two elements have a blue background and #jumbo does not have a height set.

Comment: This should clarify your thoughts : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/usbs2/6/ Does the header have a fixed width, should the bleu part adapt it's height so the content under it is visible without scrolling...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment your getting 100% of what? Nothing. You need to set the body's height so it can use that.

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/usbs2/7/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Now the blue extends down further than the window height which isnt what I want. Is it because the header is forcing it down?

Comment: Yes, the header will now force it down. At the moment it is 100% + `30px`.

Comment: @Jimmy I know there is a better way then this just cant remember right now. But your looking for something like this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/usbs2/15/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the top div has px for height and the second one is percent. Now you need to be more specific:

```
*{margin: 0px; padding 0px;}
#header {height: 30px; background-color: pink;}
#jumbo {position: absolute; top: 30px; height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: blue; display:block}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usbs2/10/

or add

```
html, body { height: 100%;  }
```